# Lightbox with Magnific pop-up not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, magnific-popup

I'm trying to use Magnific pop-up to make a lightbox for a gallery of pictures. More or less it's working but arrows doesn't appear and it doesn't close if you click outside.

So I don't know what's wrong and I'm not experienced enough to solve it.

This is the link for the website:

http://apcaadiestradoresandalucia.es/neri/pruebas/lightbox-magnific-pruebas.html

In case that something else is needed just let me know.
Many thanks in advance for your help or even interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 where this class used? ===>galeria  $('.galeria').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type:'image',
        gallery:{
          enabled:true
        }
        });
    });
```

[image]

above this is your error are you getting.

please provide some code. to look it further.
and also you are load two time jquery. one from your local server and one from live googleapi server

Comment: "Galeria" is used on the div that holds all the images for the gallery: 

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 galeria">

As for the 2 first errors about about /contactform.js 404 (not Found) I think are not related cause I didn't implement yet the "contactform", so that's why...

As for all the uncaught TypeError, no idea because are happening.

Sorry about my low programming level and about my english, both of them are doing this even harder...

What kind of code do you need???

Comment: i did'nt find Galeria as you class in your source code.
please do ctrl + u to your page and find that class. it's not there

Comment: try to your Galeria class into ===> in this tag <a href="img/port01.jpg" class="Galeria">
                            <img src="img/port01.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                          </a>

Comment: galeria is a class that I created only in order to execute the lightbox but it doesn't have any css properties. In the other hand I used it on the <a> tag as you said with no effect. But I really appreciate what you are doing Bhautik. Many thanks.